# Can a condition be referenced as a key in match?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’d like to find the lowest number in a column that is more/less than a given cell. Could I do this with MATCH? If so, how do I put in a conditional component?

I’ve tried >(cell name) and a few other things, none of which worked.

Answer (score 0):

try a custom formula under conditional formatting:

```
=(A1<B$1)*(A1=MIN(A:A))
```

or:

```
=A1=MIN(FILTER(A:A, A:A<B$1))
```

where column A are numbers and B1 is cell with your value

[image]